# How to check "Change of address" status in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, domains

I have updated my new domain using the "Change of address" tool in Google Webmaster. When I go to the [Google support page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) it shows that it may take 180 days.

How can I check the status of this process?

If I try to use "Change of Address" tool of the new domain, the page shows that "This site is undergoing a move".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've moved your domain to a new domain, you can search Google for `site:example.com` and `site:example.org`. The results should show you which domain Google is now currently indexing.

If you've moved a directory on your site, you can use `site:example.com/dir/` and `site:example.com/newdir`. This will show you which directory is now indexed.

If there are results for both of your searches, it may take time for Google to crawl all of the 301 redirects. You can get a sense of how far the progress of the move is coming along based on the number of results you see in this search.